# Trouble with Python3 Asyncio creating tasks

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, python-asyncio

Have worked through most examples but am still learning async in Python. I am having trouble why this example of code will not print "i am async".

```
import asyncio
from threading import Thread

async def cor1():
   print("i am async!")

def myasync(loop):
   print("Async running")
   loop.run_forever()
   print("Async ended?")

def main():
   this_threads_event_loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
   t_1 = Thread(target=myasync, args=(this_threads_event_loop,));
   t_1.start()
   print("begining the async loop")
   t1 = this_threads_event_loop.create_task(cor1())
   print("Finsihed cor1")

main()
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code attempts to submit tasks to the event loop from a different thread. To do that, you must use [`run_coroutine_threadsafe`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe):

```
def main():
   loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
   # start the event loop in a separate thread
   t_1 = Thread(target=myasync, args=(loop,));
   t_1.start()
   # submit the coroutine to the event loop running in the
   # other thread
   f1 = asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(cor1(), loop)
   # wait for the coroutine to finish, by asking for its result
   f1.result()
   print("Finsihed cor1")
```

Please note that combining asyncio and threads should only be done in special circumstances, such as when introducing asyncio to a legacy application where the new functionality needs to be added gradually. If you are writing new code, you almost certainly want the `main` to be a coroutine, run from top-level using [`asyncio.run(main())`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#running-an-asyncio-program).

To run a legacy synchronous function from asyncio code, you can always use [`run_in_executor`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.run_in_executor).

Comment: Sorry, if this is a silly follow up. But would f1 be = asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(coro1, this_threads_event_loop) instead of create_task?

Comment: @DrewM Yes, sorry about that!